# What is a neat way, in Python, to filter a short list to only contain unique values according to a custom comparison?

Tags: python, comparison, unique, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a short (1 - 5) list of instances of a custom class that I would like to filter so that only unique, according to my custom comparison, values remain.

What is an easy/neat/pythonic/fast way to do this? The normal way I've seen people uniqueifying lists is to put them through set(), but that doesn't really work for this because a set compares using `__hash__`, which does not allow me to compare to each other object individually.

EXTRA:

My interpretation of uniqueness is actually just having the difference between values be less than a certain value. Really it's more "closeness" than "uniqueness". This is why I cannot just check if a value has already been used, I need to check if a value is too close to any other values.

Comment: If your desired difference is `< 2` and your values are `1,2,3,4,5`, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Only one would remain, does not matter which.

Answer (score 2):

If you recast your problem into producing value *per object* that are unique per set of objects that would compare equal, you can still use a set, but use it to store the value you consider an object equal by:

```
def unique_value(obj):
    return some_calculation_over(obj)

seen = set()
filtered = [obj for obj in yourlist if unique_value(obj) not in seen and not seen.add(unique_value(obj)]
```

The alternative is to implement `__hash__` anyway, and make sure it returns *the same value* given your comparison criteria; e.g. same hash for objects that are considered equal. You also need to implement an `__eq__`  method.

If two objects are equal based on 2 attributes, then that value is a tuple of those two attributes. If you can calculate a number, and equal numbers mean equal objects, then do so, etc.

When you want to remove clusters of objects, the approach is not much different; just calculate the bucket objects fall into. Objects that are 'close' are sorted into the same bucket, leaving you with unique values (bucket identifiers).

To cluster a series of objects that are close enough, perhaps you want to *sort* the objects by the attribute, then pick off elements that are close enough:

```
def unique_close(lst, tolerance, key=None):
    if key is None:
        # identity
        key = lambda o: o
    items = iter(sorted(lst, key=key))
    first = next(items)
    prev = key(first)
    yield first
    for item in items:
        val = key(item)
        if abs(prev - val) > tolerance:
            yield item
        prev = val
```

This generator sorts your elements on your chosen key (defaults to the element itself), then only yields elements that are outside of the tolerance.

Demo:

```
>>> list(unique_close([1, 4, 5, 2, 3], 2))
[1]
>>> list(unique_close([1, 4, 5, 2, 22, 24, 3], 2))
[1, 22]
>>> list(unique_close([1, 4, 5, 2, 22, 24, 3], 3, key=lambda v: v * 2))
[1, 22, 24]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although that doesn't really apply to my situation - see edit. Sorry I wasn't clear initially, and thanks for the edit.

Comment: @SeriousSamP: You do need to be clearer *up front* then. Not that it necessarily changes things here; not if you can calculate the bucket objects fall into.

Answer (score 0):

Since `set` unfortunately does not work with custom comparisons I would wrap the objects so that they conform to your chosen comparison:

```
class Wrapped:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        # …

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # …

values = set(Wrapped(x) for x in your_list)
```

A more elegant alternative is to wrap `set` in order to provide a version which does this wrapping automatically.